# Converse of Dynkin's formula

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, markov-process, semigroup-of-operators

It is a well known (see  of theorem 19.21 of [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-4015-8)) that any Feller stochastic process $X$ with infinitesimal generator $(\mathcal{L},\mathcal{D})$ satisfies the Dynkin's formula i.e. for any $f \in \mathcal{D}$
$$
M^f_t:=f(X_t)-f(X_0)-\int_0^t \mathcal{L}f(X_s) ds
$$
is a martingale.

Is it true also the converse? Specifically, If $L$ is an elliptic (or hypoelliptic) second order operator and $X_t$ is a Markov process for which the formula above holds is it true that $X_t$ is a Feller process with infinitesimal generator $L$?

Comment: The statement of which you are seeking the converse is not about a formula that holds. Please check [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin%27s_formula) and elaborate what it has to do with the martingale property.

Comment: @KurtG. the statement is theorem 19.21 of https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-4015-8 and is a generalization of the one contained in the link you posted.

If it is not true what is the counterexample?